# SharePoint Online, how to change Group site name?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to change the group site name, and add a company logo.
When when trying to save i get the following "error":

> Classification options for your group have changed. Please select the appropriate classification.

I cant figure out what this mean and how to resolve this?

Comment: can you share the code that you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been experiencing the same issue with new groups.  After investigation the common state was that all groups had been recently created in MS Teams.  I found I was able to use Teams to change both picture and name, which was later updated in Sharepoint site.

[image: Manage Team Name]
[image: Manage Team Pic]

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Teams-and-channels-df38ae23-8f85-46d3-b071-cb11b9de5499

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce this issue when i change a Group site setting via Site information:
[image]

As a workaround, I suggest you change the settings via the Group settings:
[image]

After some time, the changes will be synced to the group site.